# JavaFX: keep window on desktop

Tags: windows, java-8, widget, javafx-2, desktop-application

I want to create a desktop widget (windows 10) with JavaFX. Is there any way to keep the window behind all others on the desktop? Also how to prevent it to minimize when clicking the show desktop button, or at least notice it.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research it seems to be impossible at the moment to do this with java, although it is possible with the win32api and c++.